# PHP variable type of class property

Tags: php, class, properties, variable-assignment

Lets take this code as an example:

```
class foo
{
    private $segments = NULL;
}
```

`$segments`  will be an array later.

**The question:**

Should i tell PHP that `$segments`   is an array (`private $segments = array();` ) or leave it as NULL?

What is better?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure it will be an array later, declare it as an array, if it may change during the program, just keep it as it is.

PHP is non-typed language, so it doesn't really matter, it just a matter of standards and habits.